# Draw scaled rectangles on scaled image canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I'm working on a project in which i need to draw an image on a canvas and rectangles also to mention the objects present on that image. Rectangles are drawing correct positions if the image is not scaling to fit to the canvas. But if i scaled the image, Rectangles are not getting scaled to meet the correct positions. I have already gone through similar questions/answers present on stackoverflow, but none of them are working in my case or may be i'm not much educated to understand and implement them in a proper way.

Following are the 2 different snippets:
[Without Image Scale](https://codepen.io/CSKAVITA/pen/VwYePwv) *(Drawing Rectangles in correct positions)* and [With Image Scale](https://codepen.io/CSKAVITA/pen/QWwydwQ)*(Drawing rectangles on incorrect position)*

Difference is just with the commented lines.

```
ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, img.width * scale, img.height * scale);
//ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); // not fitting image to canvas fill
```

and

```
ctx.strokeRect(c[0]* scale, c[1]* scale, c[2] * scale , c[3] * scale);
//ctx.strokeRect(c[0], c[1], c[2] , c[3]); //drawing rects on correct position
```

Comment: You need to add `x` and `y` to the rectangles' position: https://codepen.io/khrismuc/pen/BayjpWm (`c[0] * scale + x, c[1] * scale + y,`)

Comment: Thank you for correcting me @ChrisG. How can i mark your reply as correct answer?

Comment: No, you can only mark actual answers. I posted as comment though because this website is about generating a repository of useful questions and answers and I'm not sure this fits that purpose well enough. Are you positive the existing questions and answers you found didn't help with this at all?

Comment: You have answered my asked question and it worked like charm and fits my purpose of asking this question. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah :) Sorry, didn't mean to offend, but this website is not primarily intended to solve personal problems, like for instance Quora or Yahoo Answers. Questions and answers are supposed to benefit the community and any future visitor, otherwise they'll get removed, that's simply how it works here. (and the best way to run a Q&A site, imo) I'll gladly write a proper answer if there is no existing duplicate, but you mentioned similar questions so I'd like to make sure first.