# How to transfer rectangle coordinates from one canvas to another in Html5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I'm using some codes to dynamically *transfer co-ordinates of a rectangle on canvas* to the *another canvas* to draw rectangle on the exact position on canvas2.

I've gone through different similar questions and solutions like: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630207/transforming-coordinates-of-one-rectangle-to-another-rectangle) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59245964/draw-scaled-rectangles-on-scaled-image-canvas) on stackoverflow, but none of them is working in my case.

**sendimg()** function is transferring rectangle co-ordinates from canvas1 to the canvas2. As the canvas2 image is scaled to large size, rectangles are not drawing on the correct position.

Please check the attached snippet or  [codepen link](https://codepen.io/JackPaul/pen/XWJLYwQ) for detail.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
var rect = {};
var scale = 0;
var scale2 = 0;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var x2 = 0;
var y2 = 0;
var drag = false;


img.onload = function () {
 //Setting dpi for canvas1
 var dpi = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
 canvas.setAttribute('width', canvas.clientWidth * dpi);
 canvas.setAttribute('height', canvas.clientHeight * dpi);
 
 //Setting dpi for canvas2
 var dpi = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
 canvas2.setAttribute('width', canvas2.clientWidth * dpi);
 canvas2.setAttribute('height', canvas2.clientHeight * dpi);
    
 
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight);
 ctx.save();
 
 ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight);
 ctx2.save();
 
 //fitting image to canvas fill
 scale = Math.max(canvas.clientWidth / img.width, canvas.clientHeight / img.height); //canvas1 scale
 scale2 = Math.max(canvas2.clientWidth / img.width, canvas2.clientHeight / img.height); //canvas2 scale

    x = (canvas.clientWidth / 2) - (img.width / 2) * scale; //canvas1 x
    y = (canvas.clientHeight / 2) - (img.height / 2) * scale; //canvas1 y

 x2 = (canvas2.clientWidth / 2) - (img.width / 2) * scale2; //canvas2 x
    y2 = (canvas2.clientHeight / 2) - (img.height / 2) * scale2; //canvas2 y
 
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, img.width * scale, img.height * scale);
 ctx2.drawImage(img, x2, y2, img.width * scale2, img.height * scale2);
 
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);

}
img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/1n8sbrF.jpg';

function mouseDown(e) {
    rect.startX = e.clientX - this.offsetLeft;
    rect.startY = e.clientY - this.offsetTop;
    drag = true;
}

function mouseUp() { 
 drag = false; 
 console.log(rect);
}

function mouseMove(e) {
    if (drag) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, img.width * scale, img.height * scale);
        rect.w = (e.clientX - this.offsetLeft) - rect.startX;
        rect.h = (e.clientY - this.offsetTop) - rect.startY;
  ctx.lineWidth  = 2;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
        ctx.strokeRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
    }
}

function sendimg()
{
 if(rect.startX === undefined)
 {
  alert("draw any rectangle first on canvas1");
  return false;
 }
 ctx2.lineWidth = 2;
 ctx2.strokeStyle = "yellow";
 //Following code is not drawing rectangle on correct position
 ctx2.strokeRect(rect.startX * scale2 + x2 , rect.startY* scale2 + y2, rect.w * scale2 , rect.h * scale2);
  
}
```

```css
html, body{
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  }
#div1 {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#div2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 900px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 800px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="sendimg();">Send Rectangle on Canvas2</button>
<div id="div1">
 <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
</div>

<div id="div2">
 <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't debug your code completely, but the problem is definitely coming from the place where you define X coordinate. Since canvas.width < image.width you get value with negative number and when you apply scale2 to that value it moves left (decreases actual number since -150 is less than -100).
Basically you can see it by changing the sign to minus in `ctx2.strokeRect(rect.startX * scale2 - x2 ` (or add the absolute value of x2 instead).
Is doesn't draw the new rectangle on the exact correct place, so there is something else I guess.

Comment: Thanks @Serge P for give a try and pointing towards the clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reverse your scaling and translation of the first canvas before applying your transformation and scaling factors of the second canvas.  This is like 90% of the way there, the Y axis is correct, but the X axis is translated wrong. See my call to `ctx2.strokeRect` and how it reverses the scaling and translation.  My code is probably jacked because the canvas origin is in the top left and the formulas for translation and scaling assume it's the bottom left.

Edit: Fixed the code - it should be correct now.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
var rect = {};
var scale = 0;
var scale2 = 0;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var x2 = 0;
var y2 = 0;
var drag = false;


img.onload = function () {
 //Setting dpi for canvas1
 var dpi = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
 canvas.setAttribute('width', canvas.clientWidth * dpi);
 canvas.setAttribute('height', canvas.clientHeight * dpi);
 
 //Setting dpi for canvas2
 var dpi = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
 canvas2.setAttribute('width', canvas2.clientWidth * dpi);
 canvas2.setAttribute('height', canvas2.clientHeight * dpi);
    
 
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight);
 ctx.save();
 
 ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight);
 ctx2.save();
 
 //fitting image to canvas fill
 scale = Math.max(canvas.clientWidth / img.width, canvas.clientHeight / img.height); //canvas1 scale
 scale2 = Math.max(canvas2.clientWidth / img.width, canvas2.clientHeight / img.height); //canvas2 scale

    x = (canvas.clientWidth / 2) - (img.width / 2) * scale; //canvas1 x
    y = (canvas.clientHeight / 2) - (img.height / 2) * scale; //canvas1 y

 x2 = (canvas2.clientWidth / 2) - (img.width / 2) * scale2; //canvas2 x
    y2 = (canvas2.clientHeight / 2) - (img.height / 2) * scale2; //canvas2 y
 
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, img.width * scale, img.height * scale);
 ctx2.drawImage(img, x2, y2, img.width * scale2, img.height * scale2);
 
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
    console.log(scale)
    console.log(scale2)
}
img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/1n8sbrF.jpg';

function mouseDown(e) {
    rect.startX = e.clientX - this.offsetLeft;
    rect.startY = e.clientY - this.offsetTop;
    drag = true;
}

function mouseUp() { 
 drag = false; 
 console.log(rect);
}

function mouseMove(e) {
    if (drag) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, img.width * scale, img.height * scale);
        rect.w = (e.clientX - this.offsetLeft) - rect.startX;
        rect.h = (e.clientY - this.offsetTop) - rect.startY;
  ctx.lineWidth  = 2;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
        ctx.strokeRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
    }
}

function sendimg()
{
 if(rect.startX === undefined)
 {
  alert("draw any rectangle first on canvas1");
  return false;
 }
 ctx2.lineWidth = 2;
 ctx2.strokeStyle = "yellow";
 //Following code is not drawing rectangle on correct position
 ctx2.strokeRect( ((rect.startX - x )/scale) * scale2 + x2, 
                   ((rect.startY - y )/scale) * scale2 + y2, 
                   (rect.w/scale) * (scale2), 
                   (rect.h/scale) * (scale2));
  
}
```

```css
html, body{
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  }
#div1 {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#div2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 900px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 800px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="sendimg();">Send Rectangle on Canvas2</button>
<div id="div1">
 <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
</div>

<div id="div2">
 <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Jeff you've made it working fine. Another doubt, i want to use canvas1 only to draw rect and then pass it's cords to a python api to process these cords on the image(which is processing on python side). But this image will be on it's actual size(not the size of canvas1). how will it work when there will be no scale2? Objective is image is coming on canvas from an external api, where i need to draw rect and send it's coordinates back to the api to process further. How to modify the transforming and scaling values to work with respect to actual image size?

Answer (score 3):

### Some major and minor issues

- **IMPORTANT** When you call [`ctx.save`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save) you push the current 2D canvas state to a stack. If you don't call [`ctx.restore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore) there is no point calling [`ctx.save`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save). Worse is that every call to save is chewing up memory.
- `window` is the global this. You dont need to use it. eg `window.devicePixelRatio` is the same as `devicePixelRatio`
- You don't need to use `setAttribute`. Only use `setAttribute` when you want the Markup to reflect a properties state and the property is not defined by the DOM.
- When you set the canvas `width` or `height` the canvas is cleared and the state is reset to default. There is no need to clear the canvas after setting its size nor to save its state.
- Simplify the math. You have something like `(a / 2) - (b / 2) * c` when you calculate the origin. It has a common divisor `2` and thus becomes `(a - b) * c / 2`

### Coordinate system

Use a common coordinate system and convert when rendering to either canvas. As both canvas render the same image (and it seams that its the image that is the relevant coord system) use the image coordinate system.

You have 4 coordinate systems, the image, the scaled image canvas1, the scaled image canvas2 and `rect` as canvas1 pixels. The problem is that you are converting from canvas1 pixel coordinates (`rect`) to canvas2 image coordinates

To fix your scaling and positioning convert canvas1 pixel coordinates to the image coordinates (see example function `mouseEvents`). Then in your render function convert from image coords back to canvas pixels coords (see example function `updateCanvas`).

### Example

I removed a lot of the unneeded and repeated code to reduce complexity and make the code more readable and maintainable. Used modern JS and added some UI

- A single function to setup the canvas
- A single function to handle the mouse events
- A single function to render rectangle
- Give feedback using cursor "crosshair" and "none"

For the example I removed the button (not relevant to the question), reduced the two canvas size to fit the very small snippet window, and have the second rectangle update live as the first rectangle is being plotted.

Note that `rect` is in image coordinates.

```js
const COLOR1 = "#F00", COLOR2 = "#FF0", LINE_WIDTH = 2;
const ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d"), ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
const img = new Image;
const rect = {};
var drag = false;

img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/1n8sbrF.jpg";
img.addEventListener("load",() => {
    setupCanvas(ctx1);
    setupCanvas(ctx2);
    canvas1.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseEvent);
    canvas1.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseEvent);
    canvas1.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseEvent);
}, {once: true});

function setupCanvas(ctx, coords = {}) {
    const dPR = devicePixelRatio || 1;
    const w = ctx.canvas.width  = ctx.canvas.clientWidth * dPR;
    const h = ctx.canvas.height = ctx.canvas.clientHeight * dPR;
    const scale = coords.scale = Math.max(w / img.width, h / img.height);
    const x = coords.x = (w - img.width * scale) / 2;
    const y = coords.y = (h - img.height * scale) / 2;
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, img.width * scale, img.height * scale);
    ctx.canvas.coords = coords;
}
function mouseEvent(e) {
    var cursor = "crosshair";
    const co = canvas1.coords;
    const x = (e.clientX - this.offsetLeft - co.x) / co.scale;  
    const y = (e.clientY - this.offsetTop - co.y) / co.scale;
    if (e.type === "mousedown") {
        rect.x = x;
        rect.y = y;
        drag = true;
        canvas1.title = "";
    } else if (e.type === "mouseup") { drag = false }
    if (drag) {
        cursor = "none";
        rect.w = x - rect.x;
        rect.h = y - rect.y;
        updateCanvas(ctx1, COLOR1, co);
        updateCanvas(ctx2, COLOR2, canvas2.coords);
    }
    canvas1.style.cursor = cursor;
}

function updateCanvas(ctx, color, {x, y, scale}) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, img.width * scale, img.height * scale);
    ctx.lineWidth = LINE_WIDTH;
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.strokeRect(x + rect.x * scale, y + rect.y * scale, rect.w * scale, rect.h * scale);
}
```

```css
html, body{
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  }
#div1 {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#div2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 240px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #FF0;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
 <canvas id="canvas1" title="Click and drag to select area."></canvas>
</div>

<div id="div2">
 <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting and reducing lots of codes. You're right, i need to get rect coordinates of image(from canvas1 which is scaled) and transfer it to image2 (which will be in the actual size). Ultimately working like charm.

Comment: @JackPaul The image is scaled to fill (same method as in your question) both left and right canvas. Coords in `rect` are always in image pixel coordinates as defined by `img.width` and `img,height` this happens in the first 3 lines of `mouseEvents` . As in your question the `rect` `x`, `y` (in image coords) are set on mouse down.

Comment: Hello @Blindman67, Why the code is working fine on separately created html file, but not creating rectangle from the exact mousedown point when running it from the attached snippet? Also please check this [codepen link](https://codepen.io/JackPaul/pen/XWJvaXK) . I've changed `ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, img.width * scale, img.height * scale);` to `ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width,    img.height, 0, 0, w, h); ` to make image fit to canvas. rects are not drawing properly.